# bean named 'entityManagerFactory' could not be found

Tags: spring, sqlite, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My application fails to start. It consists of Spring Boot + JPA + SQLite. But Spring Boot and MySQL are working fine. I don't understand why this happens.

The error is

> bean named 'entityManagerFactory' could not be found

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code:

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int ContactID;
    String Number;
    String textMessage;
    String DownloadID;
    long ContactFlags;

    public int getContactID() {
        return ContactID;
    }

    public void setContactID(int contactID) {
        ContactID = contactID;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        Number = number;
    }

    public String getTextMessage() {
        return textMessage;
    }

    public void setTextMessage(String textMessage) {
        this.textMessage = textMessage;
    }

    public String getDownloadID() {
        return DownloadID;
    }

    public void setDownloadID(String downloadID) {
        DownloadID = downloadID;
    }

    public long getContactFlags() {
        return ContactFlags;
    }

    public void setContactFlags(long contactFlags) {
        ContactFlags = contactFlags;
    }
}

public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact,Integer> {
}

@Configuration
public class DBConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlite::/home/vivien/viber.db");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {    
    SQLiteDialect(){
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");
        registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StringType.INSTANCE, "", "||", "") );
        registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StringType.INSTANCE, "?1 % ?2" ) );
        registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE) );
        registerFunction( "substring", new StandardSQLFunction( "substr", StringType.INSTANCE) );
    }
    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite::/home/vivien/viber.db
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
    spring.datasource.username=
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.jpa.database-platform=com.example.demo.SQLiteDialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    @RestController
public class MyController {
     @Autowired
    ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String Hello(){
        return "Hello Sqlite";
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Contact> getAll(){
        return contactRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>
> 2018-12-25 17:35:44.340 ERROR 25591 --- [           main]
>
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ***************************************
>   APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>   ***************************************
>
> Description:
>
> Field contactRepository in com.example.demo.controller.MyController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: could you post code on MyController class?

Comment: I reformatted your question and moved the "title" inside the question body. The title is really intended for a very short description only, like the key part of an error message.

Comment: @JonathanJohx I added

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you  autowired an EntityManagerFactory in your MyController class. EntityManagerFactory is not able to be injected directly by @Autowired or @Resource

If you need dependency injection for EntityMananger, use

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I recently ran into the same problem when I added a property like `<hibernate.version>6.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>` to the pom.xml file.

The newer the better, you say?

Then I found that spring-boot-dependences-2.7.2.pom.xml has a property
`<hibernate.version>5.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>`

Which I rewrote in this way and created a problem for myself. It looks like Spring Boot JPA still doesn't know how to work with the newest version of hibernate.

For me, the solution was to remove the `<hibernate.version>` property from the pom.xml and generally the `<version>` tag from the description of the hibernate dependency.